# Getting the currently logged-in Windows Live Id (Windows Phone 7)

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-live-id

I know Windows Phone 7 requires you to enter you Windows Live Id on startup.  Is there a way to get access to information about that account from my Silverlight app installed on the phone?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried Thread.Current.Principal?

Comment: Gosh, wouldn't that be simple.  Can't wait to try it when I'm back at my desk... :>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this stage the Windows Live ID will not be available automatically to 3rd party applications. We are expecting an anonymous live id for the purpose of uniqueness identification however. Some further detail [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/9c752080-9ffb-4af5-94d4-30f0985d839c) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/48c74354-fa38-4941-857b-fcb3e46afa7b) on this topic. We'll see more on ExtendedProperties hopefully soon.

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently (with the Beta SDK) possible to get this or any other device specific information.

Apparently, in the RTM build, `DeviceExtendedProperties` will be populated with some information about device manufacture, firmware version, unique ID, etc.

This may or may not include the LiveId. I suspect that for security purposes it wouldn't though. At best we may get a hash of the id, to make it possible to identify the same person on multiple devices.