# Can I use Windows Live Id in my Windows Phone applications?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-live-id

Is there guidance out there? Samples? Is this possible?

Everything I am finding is 2010 before WP7 was even released! (including this question: [Windows Live Id Authentication for Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065343/windows-live-id-authentication-for-windows-phone-7) and [Windows Live ID Single-Sign-On on Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566971/windows-live-id-single-sign-on-on-windows-phone-7) and [Getting the currently logged-in Windows Live Id (Windows Phone 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383983/getting-the-currently-logged-in-windows-live-id-windows-phone-7) and [Messenger connect desktop API for Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250486/messenger-connect-desktop-api-for-windows-phone-7))

**Anything new?**

Comment: This article is a cool Facebook integration: http://buildmobile.com/facebook-in-a-windows-phone-7-app

Comment: what do you want to use the ID for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can, by using the windows azure access control service:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg192968